# Не работает конструкция if в js

Tags: javascript

Данный код не работает:

```
function sortSea(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        if (!item.getAttribute("data-issea")) {
            item.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
```

В качестве аргумента передается массив тегов, в которых есть data-атрибут со значениями `false`/`true`. Дебаггер показывает, что атрибуты корректно считываются, их значение получаются, но при этом класс `hidden` не присваивается. Просто все проматывается в цикле без измненений. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример массива, который вы передаете в функцию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверьте, действительно ли атрибут `false`, либо же это строка `"false"`

data-атрибуты удобно получать через `.data`

Comment: - Точно! Спасибо. Наверняка в этом и дело.

Answer (score 2):

1. Значение data-атрибута HTML-элемента всегда хранится в виде строки.
2. Для ситуаций, когда необходимы только значения `false`/`true`, есть более удобный инструмент. Проще писать этот атрибут без значений, если он есть, и не писать, если его нет. Тогда можно проверить единственным надежным способом - методом `elem.hasAttribute('attr')`.
3. Метод DOM-элемента `dataset` [плохо поддерживается IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset).